# Flutter packages won't detect memu play as emulator

Tags: android, flutter, security, virtual-machine, emulation

I'm trying to secure my app from running on rooted devices or emulators (memu play, bluestacks, ...) but the problem is these packages can't detect the emulator

till now i used
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_jailbreak_detection
https://pub.dev/packages/safe_device

also i used
isPhysicalDevice from
https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus

and i used
https://pub.dev/packages/root
to detect if device is rooted or not

this is result in memu play

- from device_info_plus

isPhysical: true

- from root

root: false

- from safe_device

isJailBroken: false
isRealDevice: true